# Regular Expressions in Notepad++ startwith and endwith text and remove all unmatched text

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to write a regular expression that starts with the string "Row data=" and ends with the string ".  ", then remove all unmatched text. How do I do it?

Example log file:

```
[ERROR] 2016-07-01 17:17:05,263(2715503)-->[main] csvRowToObject(ApmInfoCSVDao.java:93): Error occured while parsing ApmInfo Object: usrid=2111840,
 Row data=2111840   ABC     XYZ EFC 1971-03-27 00:00:00.000 1971    03  27  1   111064287   1114007  SA:E1801.  
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "XYZ EFC"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
[ERROR] 2016-07-01 17:17:05,325(2715565)-->[main] csvRowToObject(ApmInfoCSVDao.java:93): Error occured while parsing ApmInfo Object: usrid=2058318,
 Row data=2058318   PP      XX YY   1970-07-27 00:00:00.000 1970    07  27  1   111049159   1065120  SA:332.  
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "XX YY"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
```

I want to obtain:

```
Row data=2111840    ABC     XYZ EFC 1971-03-27 00:00:00.000 1971    03  27  1   111064287   1114007  SA:E1801.  
Row data=2058318    PP      XX YY   1970-07-27 00:00:00.000 1970    07  27  1   111049159   1065120  SA:332.
```

Here is real text after show all hidden characters(space and TAB) :

```
 Row data=2111840<tab>ABC<tab><tab>XYZ<tab>EFC<tab>1971-03-27 00:00:00.000<tab>1971<tab>03<tab>27<tab>1<tab>111064287<tab>1114007<tab>SA:E1801.
```

I tried searching the regexp `^ Row data*\.  )$` , but it says 0 matches

How can i do this in Notepad ++?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative look ahead for the start of line and a negative character class for the end:

```
Search: ^((?! Row data=).*|.*[^.\s])\s*[\r\n]+
Replace: <blank>
```

This will delete lines that start with `" Row data="` but don't end with a dot and visa versa.

Tested with the sample input in the question.

Comment: thanks guy,  I have updated my question. 

the real text data is here(show all hidden characters):   

     Row data=2111840<tab>ABC<tab><tab>XYZ<tab>EFC<tab>1971-03-27 00:00:00.000<tab>1971<tab>03<tab>27<tab>1<tab>111064287<tab>1114007<tab>SA:E1801.

Comment: @sdev try modified answer

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

Find: `^(?!(\s*Row data=.+\.)).+(\n|\r)*`

Replace with empty.